# vscode: get rid of message in js and ts files: 'exported identifier should have comment or be unexported'

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

In vscode I am not sure when this started or what extension I have installed but lately I see this message 'exported identifier should have comment or be unexported'.

A brief google search leads me to believe that this is from golang syntax checking. But I am using .js files and .ts files. So why is this error shown and how to fix it?

List of extensions installed obtained using code --list-extensions:

```
abierbaum.vscode-file-peek
adashen.vscode-tomcat
akamud.vscode-theme-onelight
alefragnani.project-manager
alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings
Angular.ng-template
arashmidos.kill-comments
asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode
bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client
ChaunceyKiwi.json-tree-view
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
ClemensPeters.format-json
codezombiech.gitignore
cstechnologies.vscode-storybook
ctf0.command-autolink
ctf0.htmlhint
danh42.terminal-file-link
DanLevett.pattern-links
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
denoland.vscode-deno
developersoapbox.vscode-springboot-snippets
dgileadi.java-decompiler
docsmsft.docs-yaml
donjayamanne.git-extension-pack
donjayamanne.githistory
donjayamanne.javadebugger
DotJoshJohnson.xml
eamodio.gitlens
ebrithil30.vscode-ts-auto-return-type
ecmel.vscode-spring-boot
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
eg2.vscode-npm-script
Equinusocio.vsc-community-material-theme
Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme
equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons
eriklynd.json-tools
esbenp.prettier-vscode
FerrierBenjamin.fold-unfold-all-icone
file-icons.file-icons
foxundermoon.shell-format
Fr43nk.seito-openfile
GabrielBB.vscode-lombok
gbenga504.js-docusaurus
georgewfraser.vscode-javac
ghmcadams.lintlens
GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github
GregChamblin.vscode-json-editor
Gruntfuggly.todo-tree
howgraceu.vue-file-peek
humao.rest-client
IBM.output-colorizer
ionutvmi.path-autocomplete
ipedrazas.kubernetes-snippets
ithildir.java-properties
jackfranklin.vscode-go-to-file
JakeWilson.vscode-cdnjs
jkiviluoto.tws
jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager
jock.svg
johnpapa.vscode-peacock
jonwolfe.prettier-eslint-formatter
joyous-coder.springboot-extension-pack
k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings
KabirSarkar.spring-boot-gradle-extension-pack
kboris.jsmm
kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics
laurencebahiirwa.deno-std-lib-snippets
loiane.java-spring-extension-pack
loilo.snazzy-light
luchanso.format-me
maptz.regionfolder
marco-pierobon.git-graphy
marcoLee.testfile-generator-for-junit
mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin
mflo999.lintel
mhutchie.git-graph
MicroProfile-Community.mp-rest-client-generator-vscode-ext
MicroProfile-Community.mp-starter-vscode-ext
MicroProfile-Community.vscode-microprofile-pack
mike-co.import-sorter
mintlify.linked
mrmlnc.vscode-apache
ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime
ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-aks-tools
ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools
ms-mssql.data-workspace-vscode
ms-mssql.mssql
ms-mssql.sql-bindings-vscode
ms-mssql.sql-database-projects-vscode
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack
ms-vscode.azure-account
ms-vscode.azurecli
ms-vscode.powershell
ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings
msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge
MuTsunTsai.jsdoc-link
mwpb.java-prettier-formatter
naco-siren.gradle-language
naumovs.color-highlight
nick-rudenko.back-n-forth
nickdemayo.vscode-json-editor
nilpatel.title
Nixon.env-cmd-file-syntax
Noctarya.terminals
Noctarya.typescript-web-development-extension-pack
onecrayon.theme-quietlight-vsc
oouo-diogo-perdigao.docthis
Owokoyo.cdo-sync
patcx.vscode-nuget-gallery
Perkovec.jsdoc-live-preview
Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack
Pivotal.vscode-concourse
Pivotal.vscode-manifest-yaml
Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot
PKief.material-icon-theme
pranaygp.vscode-css-peek
pucelle.vscode-css-navigation
pverest.java-ide-pack
rbbit.typescript-hero
redhat.fabric8-analytics
redhat.java
redhat.vscode-commons
redhat.vscode-microprofile
redhat.vscode-xml
redhat.vscode-yaml
ricardo-emerson.java-sysout
riccardoforina.storybook-helper
richardwillis.vscode-gradle-extension-pack
richardwillis.vscode-gradle-preview
richardwillis.vscode-spotless-gradle
rintoj.blank-line-organizer
rioj7.html-related-links
robberphex.php-debug
rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint
ryanmcalister.unotes
Shan.code-settings-sync
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
shengchen.vscode-checkstyle
shinworks.jsdoc-view
slevesque.vscode-link
SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode
spmeesseman.vscode-taskexplorer
stephenwassell.light-high-contrast-theme
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
Summer.azure-event-hub-explorer
svipas.code-autocomplete
TabNine.tabnine-vscode
tenjojeremy.open-storybook-story
tht13.html-preview-vscode
tintinweb.vscode-decompiler
Tobermory.es6-string-html
uctakeoff.vscode-counter
usernamehw.errorlens
vikas.code-navigation
VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode-completions
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode-insiders
VisualStudioOnlineApplicationInsights.application-insights
vscjava.vscode-gradle
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard
vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr
WakaTime.vscode-wakatime
wesleyegberto.vscode-java-tests
Wscats.java-snippet
XieXiuYue.ts-file-skip
yangbaopan.vscode-java-ibatisx
YouMayCallMeV.vscode-java-saber
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
zenclabs.previewjs
zh9528.file-size
ziyasal.vscode-open-in-github
```

Comment: Any chance you've installed the Go extension for VS Code?

Comment: attached is output of `code --list extensions` :

Comment: The easiest way to find if it is an extension issue is by running the `Bisect` command - it quickly narrows down which is the offending extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also experiencing this error.

Here are the common extensions between our systems:

```
[
    "christian-kohler.npm-intellisense",
    "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
    "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "eamodio.gitlens",
    "gbenga504.js-docusaurus",
    "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github",
    "Gruntfuggly.todo-tree",
    "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
    "ms-python.python",
    "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
    "ms-toolsai.jupyter",
    "ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap",
    "ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers",
    "ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers",
    "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh",
    "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit",
    "ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack",
    "ms-vscode.powershell",
    "naumovs.color-highlight",
    "rbbit.typescript-hero",
    "redhat.java",
    "redhat.vscode-commons",
    "redhat.vscode-yaml",
    "VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples",
    "VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode",
    "vscjava.vscode-java-debug",
    "vscjava.vscode-java-dependency",
    "vscjava.vscode-java-pack",
    "vscjava.vscode-java-test",
    "vscjava.vscode-maven",
    "WakaTime.vscode-wakatime",
    "yzhang.markdown-all-in-one"
]
```

I went and disabled all and then enabled each one by one. This silly linting issue is coming from the js-docusaurus extension.

Specifically from here:

https://github.com/gbenga504/js-docusaurus/blob/18369b8631e725acf795e68b92f92ccd2fbdd383/src/LintService.ts#L118

Just disable this extension and then try again.

The frustrating thing is that this linting warning is similar to  a Go lint warning so it's been tough to track down the root cause.

Comment: Yes I recall that I had hunted this down in some similar way and this was the extension causing the problem. But I forgot to update here earlier. Thanks!